# jquery ajax response + function calling process in different AppDomain

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, appdomain

From my asp.net web app I'm calling a WebMethod in a WebService on button click using jquery ajax. This webmethod starts a process on the server in a different AppDomain. When the process is started without switching to another AppDomain the jquery ajax response is received accordingly after 2 milliseconds, however when the process is in another AppDomain the response is never received and Success is never reached although the process is triggered successfully, and this causes other functions to also get delayed. Any idea what could be causing this issue please?

```
function startTests() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "DataServices/DataServices.asmx/startTests",
        dataType: "text",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {

                showWarning("Started Test Execution", 5000);

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSONP. It allows cross-domain AJAX calls.

[json-p.org/](http://json-p.org/%E2%80%8E)‎